# How do I implement a multi-select dropdown filter with checkboxes using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I want to implement a filter that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msb5Y.png). The log is for events and i want to filter based on event status

I have tried looping through events and getting event.status but i get error that says status undefined. I have tried hard coding the options but i cant get the checkbox to show. I'm not bothered about logic or functionality now, I just want want to implement the UI.

Here is my HTML code
`

```
    <div class="select">
    <select [ngClass]="{ active: !!eventApp }" aria-label="frequency" [(ngModel)]="eventApp" (change)="getEvents()">
            <option value="">Status</option>
            <option [value]="event.uid" *ngFor="let event of events?.content">
{{event.status}}
            </option>
    </select>
    </div>

`
```

The above is not working, should i hard code the options? Successful, failed, retry. I have tried doing that, but the checkboxes don't show.

Comment: Did you investigate if the `select` tag supports adding a checkbox?

Comment: I just did, it doesn't. So know I have to figure out how to use the ng-multiselect tag.

Comment: Kris, you can use a multi-select or create one yourself. The difficult part is to place the "dropdown" generally if you're planning use material-angular, you can use a mat-menu and if you're using ng-bootstrap you use a ngb-dropdonw. Also you can simply use a a div with position relative and inside a div with position absolute, or use bootstrap 5 directly -I don't recomended this last- or use one of the severals multiselect there're. What are you looking for?